# Open sets in the infinite product of $\mathbb{N}^\infty$

Tags: general-topology, infinite-product, natural-numbers, product-space

How can I see that the open sets in the infinite product of $\mathbb{N}^\infty$
in the product topology with all components being the discrete topology are exactly the sets extending the given finite sequence ?

Comment: The product topology has to make each projection continuous and be as coarse as possible. So, it needs to be generated by the preimages of open sets by each projection. The open sets of $\mathbb{N}$ are any subset $A\subset\mathbb{N}$. Its preimage by the $k$-th projection is the set $U_{A,k}=\mathbb{N}^{k-1}\times A\times\mathbb{N}^{\infty-k-1}$. Note how for every element of $\mathbb{N}^k\times A$, which is a finite tuple, you can append an arbitrary sequence of natural numbers to it as a tail and that would be an element of $U_{A,k}$. ...

Comment: Next we check how arbitrary unions of sets like $U_{A,k}$ still have this property. If $I\subset \mathbb{N}$, then there is a minimum element $k_0$ of $I$, then $\bigcup_{k\in I}U_{A_k,k}=B\times\mathbb{N}^{\infty-k_0}$, with $B\subset\mathbb{N}^{k_0-1}$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy "For every element of $\mathbb{N}^{k-1}\times A$" and not $\mathbb{N}^{k}\times A$ , right ? And you mean arbitrary **infinite** sequence, can be appended, right ? And yet, what role plays the fact that $k_0$ is minimal (so that I can decode what you write in your second comment) ?

Comment: Yes, elements of the first chunk up to $A$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy  What about my next 2 questions please ?

Comment: Infinite sequence, yes. The point of $k_0$ being minimal is that after that, because of the union, the tail is arbitrary, because in the union there would be the element $U_{A_{k_0},k_0}=\mathbb{N}^{k_0-1}\times A_{k_0}\times\mathbb{N}^{\infty-k_0}$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy And what about your set $B$, does it have our property that it contains our sequence as well ? Or how does $B$ look like ?

Comment: The $B$ doesn't have any other restriction. It contains some finite sequences and not others. The point is that the open sets of $\mathbb{N}^{\infty}$ contain sequences with certain collection $B$ of initial finite sequences, and then examples with those starting chunks and any tail that you might want (the arbitrary elements of $\mathbb{N}^{\infty-k_0}$).

Answer (score 1):

The standard base for the product topology on $\Bbb N^\infty$ is all sets of the
form $\prod_{n \in \omega} U_n$ where all $U_n \subseteq \Bbb N$ and all but finitely many $U_n$ are equal to $\Bbb N$ (i.e. $\{n \in \omega: U_n \neq \Bbb N\}$ is a finite set).

But we can WLOG assume that the finitely many proper subsets are all singletons and occur as the initial part of $\omega$ and then we still have a base, which is smaller (call such basic open sets "simple basic sets" for now):

Let $U=\prod_n U_n$ be a basic subset as described in the beginning and let $(x_n) \in U$. Let $\{n \in \omega: U_n \neq \Bbb N\}$ have $N$ as its maximum element.

Then define $V:= \prod_n V_n$ to be the basic subset with $V_n = \{x_n\}$ for all $n \le N$ and $V_n = \Bbb N$ otherwise. This by construction is a simple basic set and $(x_n) \in V$ is obvious and so is $V \subseteq U$.

As we can do this for all $(x_n) \in U$, every standard basis set is a union of "simple basic sets" and so all open sets are unions of "simple basic sets", and these are precisely the sets of the form

$B((a_1,\ldots,a_n)) := \{(x_n) \in \Bbb N^\omega: (x_n)_n \text{ extends } a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n\}$

So you can say that $O$ in the product is open iff for each $x \in O$ there is some initial part $x|N$ of $x$, such that *all* sequences that extend $x|N$ are also in $O$, which is the more precise version of your "extension characterisation".